Python/Pandas - Create lookup table of items bought together
I'm struggling a bit trying to create a lookup table of items that are bought together.
I have a solution in "brute force" Python iterating over a DataFrame, but I'd prefer one in pure Pandas using some kind of aggregate trick if possible.
Here is what I have. I've made a small example with a list of invoice numbers and what item that was bought.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Invoice": [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5], 
    "Item": ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Apple", "Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Apple", "Orange"]
})
df

We can see that invoice number 4 has three items and invoice number 2 has just one.
And here is my solution that I'm not really happy with:
item_keys = []
item_values = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    invoice = row["Invoice"]
    item = row["Item"]
    for item_2 in df[df["Invoice"] == invoice]["Item"]:
        if item_2 != item:
            item_keys.append(item)
            item_values.append(item_2)

lookup_table = pd.DataFrame({"key": item_keys, "value": item_values})
lookup_table

In lookup_table I can then search for a key item and gett all items that were sold together with it.
Is there a faster and more elegant way to do this?)

You can also do a self join and filter down:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Invoice": [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5],
    "Item": ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Apple", "Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Apple", "Orange"]
})

lookup_table = (
    df.merge(df, on='Invoice')
    .rename(columns={'Item_x': 'key', 'Item_y': 'value'})
    .loc[lambda d: (d['key'] != d['value'])]
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    # .drop(columns='Invoice') # uncomment to remove the 'Invoice' column
)

print(lookup_table)
#    Invoice     key   value
# 0        1   Apple    Pear
# 1        1    Pear   Apple
# 2        4   Apple  Orange
# 3        4   Apple    Pear
# 4        4  Orange   Apple
# 5        4  Orange    Pear
# 6        4    Pear   Apple
# 7        4    Pear  Orange
# 8        5   Apple  Orange
# 9        5  Orange   Apple


Reading your question I think is better to create cross-tabulation from your dataframe, e.g.:
cross_table = pd.crosstab(df["Invoice"], df["Item"])

print(cross_table)

Prints:
Item     Apple  Banana  Orange  Pear
Invoice                             
1            1       0       0     1
2            0       1       0     0
3            1       0       0     0
4            1       0       1     1
5            1       0       1     0


Then to find with what items for example Apple was bought:
print(cross_table[cross_table["Apple"].eq(1)].any())

Prints:
Item
Apple      True
Banana    False
Orange     True
Pear       True
dtype: bool

You see Apple was sold together with Orange and Pear

You could use groupby and itertools.combinations:
from itertools import combinations

lst = [c for _, g in df.groupby('Invoice')['Item']
       for c in combinations(g, 2)]

out = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['key', 'value']),
                 pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['value', 'key'])],
                ignore_index=True)

Output:
      key   value
0   Apple    Pear
1   Apple  Orange
2   Apple    Pear
3  Orange    Pear
4   Apple  Orange
5    Pear   Apple
6  Orange   Apple
7    Pear   Apple
8    Pear  Orange
9  Orange   Apple

Sorted variant:
from itertools import combinations

lst = [c for _, g in df.groupby('Invoice')['Item']
       for c in combinations(g, 2)]

out = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['key', 'value']),
                  pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['value', 'key'])])
         .sort_values(by=['key', 'value'], ignore_index=True)
       )

Output:
      key   value
0   Apple  Orange
1   Apple  Orange
2   Apple    Pear
3   Apple    Pear
4  Orange   Apple
5  Orange   Apple
6  Orange    Pear
7    Pear   Apple
8    Pear   Apple
9    Pear  Orange

